# how to use strings in a file as a variable

Tags: shell-script

I have a conf file content like below.

file.conf:

```
key name
value pswd
```

Now I want write a script to have the two variable as above

script.sh

```
key="name"      #key as variable
value="pswd"    #value as variable
```

`. /path/to/file.conf` is giving me key & value command not found error.

Comment: What shell are you using to source the file? Is it bash/sh/dash or similar or csh/tcsh or something else?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 awk 'NF>1 { var=$1 ; $1 = "" ; printf "%s=\"%s\"\n",var,$0; }' file.conf > script.sh
```

this awk line basically use first filed (when more than two) as var name, then the remaining of line as value (hence the `$1=""` dirty trick).

As per Terdon suggestion, provided value have no space in it.

```
 awk '{print $1 "=" $2 }' file.conf > script.sh
```

Comment: Why `NF>1`? Also, why not just `awk '{print $1"="$2}'` or, to get the quotes `awk '{print $1"=\""$2"\""}'`. And your approach will add a leading space to the value: `key=" name"` instead of `key="name"`

Comment: what about foo="foo bar" ? I agree on unwanted whitespace.

Comment: Ah, yes. I don't know if that will ever happen though.

Comment: You could also use sub and that will work for spaces as well: `awk '{sub(/ /,"=\""); sub(/$/,"\"");print}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your shell is bourne-style, where variables are defined with `var="value"`, with GNU `sed`, you can do:

```
sed -i 's/ /="/;s/$/"/' file.conf
```

Or

```
sed -i -e 's/ /="/' -e 's/$/"/' file.conf
```

Or

```
perl -i -pe 's/ /="/;s/$/"/' file.conf
```

These are all basically the same idea. In both GNU `sed` and `perl`, the `-i` switch will edit the file in place and `s/foo/bar/` will substitute `foo` with `bar` on every input line. So, the first substitution will replace the 1st space with `="` and the second substitution will add a `"` at the end of the line (`$`).

All of these will convert this:

```
key name
value pswd
key1 foo bar
```

To this:

```
key="name"
value="pswd"
key1="foo bar"
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. I m unable to understand.

Comment: @Raja in order for bourne-family shells (like `sh` or `bash`) to read variables, they need to be in this format: `var="value"`. The commands I show change your `file.conf` to that format. After running one of them, you will be able to do `. file.conf` as you wanted.

Comment: So brother ,for command you want me to use google,sure I will.

Comment: @Raja is that better? Next time, instead of leaving snarky comments you should be more specific. I had no idea which part you didn't understand.

Comment: I want to get that output in my way but stuck here , Please have a look and suggest me please  "while read line; do v1=`head -n 1 file1 | cut -d " " -f 1`; v2=`head -n 1 file1 | cut -d " " -f 2`; echo "\"$v1"\=\"$v2"\"" >> file2 ; done < file1"

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted what you wanted a little differently ... i.e. that you want a way to source `file.conf` as if it were a set of shell variable assignments - so instead of

```
. /path/to/file.conf
```

try using

```
eval `while read var val; do echo "${var}='${val}'"; done < /path/to/file.conf`
```

You would need to be sure that the format of `file.conf` did not deviate from what you have described here.

Note that I am deliberately using eval on the entire output rather than calling eval on each assignment inside the loop, because I'm not sure if variable assignments will be global there (they may be done in a sub-shell because of the redirected input - does anyone know for sure? I suppose I could just test it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes may not be the best choice of quotes there as within them, the `$`, `"`, backslash and backtick characters are still special.

I'd use single quote characters instead (`key='name'`) as then the only character you need to worry about is `'` itself.

```
sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/ /='/;s/\$/'/" < file.conf > file.sh
```